# How to use react router on footer

Tags: reactjs

I am on a project with my friends. I have to take care the FAQ. The issue is that the react router is already used on that he header. And i don't know how to use the react router on the footer.

Comment: Please add more details. You might have to use use the <Link to=path> from react router.

Answer (score -1):

There should not be issue with footer. You can have single router index file and can add Link tag in your components. Can you explain your query? What challenge you facing with router in footer?